# c++ Heap warning: Free heap block modified after it was freed

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have the following class and code:

```
template <class T>
class HashTable {

struct Pair{
    T element;
    int key;
    Pair(T element, int Key) : element(element), key(key) {};
};

int table_size;
int counter;
List<Pair> (*elements);

void changeTableSize(int newSize){
    List<Pair> *temp = new List<Pair>[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++){
        for (typename List<Pair>::Iterator j = elements[i].begin(); j != elements[i].end(); j++){
            Pair  p = *j;
            temp[p.key % newSize].insert(Pair(p.element, p.key));
        }
    }
    delete[] elements;
    elements = temp;
    table_size = newSize;
}

public:
    HashTable() : table_size(100), counter(0){
        elements = new List<Pair>[table_size];
    };
void insert(T data, int key){
    if (member(key)){
        throw ElementAlreadyExists();
    }
    elements[key % table_size].insert(Pair (data, key));
    counter++;
    if (counter == table_size){
        changeTableSize(table_size*2);
    }
};
```

When I call changeTableSize() the first time, everything is fine. When I call it the second time my program crashes saying "warning: HEAP: Free Heap block 006618C0 modified at 006618D4 after it was freed" right after the allocation for temp. What can cause this?

Comment: You can't use `elements` without initializing it.

Comment: You delete *elements* , then assign *temp* to it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore elements is initialized in a constructor not shown here.

Comment: @StephaneRolland typename is fine.

Comment: @SChepurin what should I do then, and why is that a problem?

Comment: @DanDv - The problem - "Free Heap block 006618C0 modified at 006618D4 after it was freed."

Comment: @StephaneRolland otherwise it gives an error "need 'typename' before 'List<Table<T>::Pair>::Iterator' because 'List<Table<T>::Pair>' is a dependent scope"

Comment: @SChepurin where was it modified? I am freeing the previous array, then I allocate new space for it in every call of the function.

Comment: @Dan Dv- You should *delete* what was allocated with *new* and not trying to assign anything to already deleted.

Comment: @SChepurin You are mistaken. Assigning a new value to elements after freeing the memory it used to point to is perfectly valid.

Comment: @SChepurin elements does point to an address in the heap. In every call to the function, I copy its contents to a new array, delete it, and then tell elements to point to the new array that I allocated. Why is it wrong? Do you have a suggestion in code that I can do in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: @SChepurin What does my code do then? Can you point me to the problem?

Comment: @DanDv Please post definitions for `Pair` and `List`. Also post the calling code. There is at least one error in your code: The constructor for `Table` is private.

Comment: @Alan Stokes  and DanDv - Only now see the constructor for *elements*.

Comment: @DanDv There is a typo in the constructor for `Pair`. It should be `key` instead of `Key`. I still cannot see a problem. I guess the reason for the error is in either `List` or the calling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If originalSize > table_size then you are performing an illegal memory access in the inner 'for' loop.

Remove the 'originalSize' argument that you are passing to the function.

Use the class variable 'table_size' instead, and update it to the new size before you return.

Also, make sure that class Pair has a copy-constructor properly defined and implemented:

```
Pair(const Pair& pair)
{
    // For each variable x of pair, that points to dynamically-allocated memory:
    // this->x = new ...
    // memcpy(this->x,pair.x,...)

    // For each variable y of pair, that doesn't point to dynamically-allocated memory:
    // this->y = pair.y
}
```

Otherwise, you might have two different instances of class Pair with internal variables pointing to the same dynamically-allocated memory. And when one instance is destroyed, the internal variables of the other instance will point to an already-freed memory.

Comment: Edited, note the constructor. elements does point to the heap

Comment: Why is it wrong to do what I did? I am allocating space for temp, I delete elements, then I tell elements to point at temp.

Comment: Correct, I see that now. So answer changed again. And you still need to delete elements in ~Table()...

Comment: Did you also set 'table_size' to the new value as described in the revised answer?

Comment: yep. table_size = newSize

Comment: Does class Pair have a copy-constructor properly defined and implemented? Pair(const Pair& pair){/* copy all internal data of 'pair' into 'this' */}

Comment: Please see revised answer on 'why it may be essential for you to do so'